# AVG of 3 SELECT statements with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do the following

I have a table QA which contains the following:

```
TICKET_ID   SKILL_ID  SCORE         USER
###############################################
1           10          15          USER1
1           20           5          USER1
1           30          95          USER1
2           40          20          USER1
2           50          40          USER1
3           60          70          USER1
3           70          15          USER1
```

a table SKILLS made of:

```
SKILL_ID   SKILL_NAME   AREA_ID
   10       SKILL1        1
   20       SKILL2        1
   30       SKILL3        2
   40       SKILL4        2
   50       SKILL5        2
   60       SKILL6        3
   70       SKILL7        3
```

and a table TICKETS made of:

```
  TICKET_ID   TICKET_NUMBER   
    1           AAA
    2           BBB
    3           CCC
```

QA  has a FK to TICKETS using TICKET_ID and also a FK to SKILLS using SKILL_ID

What I would need to do is:

for each ticket in table QA check that the sum of the score in every area does not go over 100 and if over count as a 0, then make the AVG of the 3 results and group by the ticket_number which is in another table
So for each case I would need to count the score for each area, if > 100 then 0 else leave the original value then make the average of the 3 values and group by the ticket number

Not sure if this is possible

So perhaps to calculate the score of area_1 I do the following:

```
SELECT DECODE(100 - SUM(SCORE),
100,100,
95,95,
90,90,
85,85,
80,80,
75,75,
70,70,
65,65,
60,60,
55,55,
50,50,
45,45,
40,40,
35,35,
30,30,
25,25,
20,20,
15,15,
10,10,
5,5,
0) SCORE_A1 FROM QA WHERE SKILL_ID IN(SELECT SKILL_ID FROM SKILLS WHERE AREA_ID = 1) AND TICKET_NUMBER = :P2_TICKET_NUMBER AND QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY 1
```

to calculate the score of area_2 same thing but changing the WHERE condition ( WHERE AREA_ID = 2 this time):

```
SELECT DECODE(100 - SUM(SCORE),
100,100,
95,95,
90,90,
85,85,
80,80,
75,75,
70,70,
65,65,
60,60,
55,55,
50,50,
45,45,
40,40,
35,35,
30,30,
25,25,
20,20,
15,15,
10,10,
5,5,
0) SCORE_A1 FROM QA WHERE SKILL_ID IN(SELECT SKILL_ID FROM SKILLS WHERE AREA_ID = 2) AND TICKET_NUMBER = :P2_TICKET_NUMBER AND QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY 1
```

and to calculate the score of area_3 same thing but changing the WHERE condition ( WHERE AREA_ID = 3 ):

```
SELECT DECODE(100 - SUM(SCORE),
100,100,
95,95,
90,90,
85,85,
80,80,
75,75,
70,70,
65,65,
60,60,
55,55,
50,50,
45,45,
40,40,
35,35,
30,30,
25,25,
20,20,
15,15,
10,10,
5,5,
0) SCORE_A1 FROM QA WHERE SKILL_ID IN(SELECT SKILL_ID FROM SKILLS WHERE AREA_ID = 3) AND TICKET_NUMBER = :P2_TICKET_NUMBER AND QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY 1
```

Each one of this blocks gives 1 value as output

What I'm trying to achieve is having as output the AVG of the 3 blocks by ticket_number

I tried to sum the 3 blocks all together but it doesn't allow me  :

```
SELECT DECODE(100 - SUM(SCORE),
100,100,
95,95,
90,90,
85,85,
80,80,
75,75,
70,70,
65,65,
60,60,
55,55,
50,50,
45,45,
40,40,
35,35,
30,30,
25,25,
20,20,
15,15,
10,10,
5,5,
0) SCORE_A1 FROM QA WHERE SKILL_ID IN(SELECT SKILL_ID FROM SKILLS WHERE AREA_ID = 1) AND TICKET_NUMBER = :P2_TICKET_NUMBER AND QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY 1
+
SELECT DECODE(100 - SUM(SCORE),
100,100,
95,95,
90,90,
85,85,
80,80,
75,75,
70,70,
65,65,
60,60,
55,55,
50,50,
45,45,
40,40,
35,35,
30,30,
25,25,
20,20,
15,15,
10,10,
5,5,
0) SCORE_A1 FROM QA WHERE SKILL_ID IN(SELECT SKILL_ID FROM SKILLS WHERE AREA_ID = 2) AND TICKET_NUMBER = :P2_TICKET_NUMBER AND QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY 1
+
SELECT DECODE(100 - SUM(SCORE),
100,100,
95,95,
90,90,
85,85,
80,80,
75,75,
70,70,
65,65,
60,60,
55,55,
50,50,
45,45,
40,40,
35,35,
30,30,
25,25,
20,20,
15,15,
10,10,
5,5,
0) SCORE_A1 FROM QA WHERE SKILL_ID IN(SELECT SKILL_ID FROM SKILLS WHERE AREA_ID = 3) AND TICKET_NUMBER = :P2_TICKET_NUMBER AND QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Please note that with your DECODE expression if your 100 - SUM(SCORE) is not divisible by 5 there will be a ZERO as a result. I.e. if  100 - SUM(SCORE) = 73 there will be 0. Is this what you expect?

Comment: Could you confirm you are using Oracle (`DECODE` function)?

Comment: Hello,thanks for the reply, I'm using oracle 12c so yes it's the oracle decode function. How would you check instead of using the decode function ? I've seen that you can embed a case inside a select but the main problem is that I don't know how to put all togheter in order to have the average of the 3 areas for each ticket number Thank you

Comment: @ChrisA. Hi Please find the answers below. I hope you can get needed help. Regards

Comment: Please add information to your question by making an [edit] to it, rather than burying it in the comments where it can be lost in the clutter.  It also helps, particularly with SQL, to include a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them. Also, it is not necessary to SHOUT the information in your question title.

Comment: Hi Ken,
I just joined the forum so I may not know all the rules yet
Anyway I don't think I was shouting in the title, as you can see, the upper case are just the SQL commands... which usually go in upper case..

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT
    AREAS_SCORES.USER,
    AREAS_SCORES.TICKET_ID,
    AREAS_SCORES.TICKET_NUMBER,
    AVG(CASE 
            WHEN AREAS_SCORES.AREA_SUM_SCORE > 100 THEN 0
            ELSE AREAS_SCORES.AREA_SUM_SCORE
        END) AVG_SCORE
FROM
(
    SELECT
        QA.USER,
        QA.TICKET_ID,
        QA.TICKET_NUMBER,
        SKILLS.AREA_ID,
        SUM(QA.SCORE) AREA_SUM_SCORE
    FROM 
        QA 
        INNER JOIN SKILLS ON SKILLS.SKILL_ID = QA.SKILL_ID
        INNER JOIN TICKETS ON TICKETS.TICKET_ID = QA.TICKET_ID
    GROUP BY
        QA.USER,
        QA.TICKET_ID,
        QA.TICKET_NUMBER,
        SKILLS.AREA_ID
) AREAS_SCORES
```

The subquery calculates score sum within each area for each ticket of each user. Then the information is aggregated again to count the average but with the restriction that when sum of scores for a particular area exceeds `100`, then it should be counted as `0`.

I hope it helps some way (assuming I understood your problem well).

Comment: Hi @Chris. I'm really glad it might occur useful. Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all with a single select. You will have to combine the `SUM` with the `CASE`, like this:

```
SELECT T.TICKET_NUMBER,
SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 1 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A1,
SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 2 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A2,
SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 3 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A3
FROM QA INNER JOIN SKILLS S ON QA.SKILL_ID = S.SKILL_ID
INNER JOIN TICKETS T ON QA.TICKET_ID = T.TICKET_ID
WHERE QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY T.TICKET_NUMBER
```

Now, to apply an additional criteria to make sure the SUM does not go over 100 use a outer query:

```
SELECT TICKET_NUMBER,
CASE WHEN SCORE_A1 > 100 THEN 0 ELSE SCORE_A1 END SCORE_A1,
CASE WHEN SCORE_A2 > 100 THEN 0 ELSE SCORE_A2 END SCORE_A2,
CASE WHEN SCORE_A3 > 100 THEN 0 ELSE SCORE_A3 END SCORE_A3
FROM 
   (
    SELECT T.TICKET_NUMBER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 1 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 2 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 3 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A3
    FROM QA INNER JOIN SKILLS S ON QA.SKILL_ID = S.SKILL_ID
    INNER JOIN TICKETS T ON QA.TICKET_ID = T.TICKET_ID
    WHERE QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY T.TICKET_NUMBER
   ) TIX
```

And finally, if you need an average of these three scores use another level of outer queries:

```
SELECT TICKET_NUMBER,
SCORE_A1,
SCORE_A2,
SCORE_A3,
(SCORE_A1+SCORE_A2+SCORE_A3)/3 AVG_SCORE
FROM
   (
    SELECT TICKET_NUMBER,
    CASE WHEN SCORE_A1 > 100 THEN 0 ELSE SCORE_A1 END SCORE_A1,
    CASE WHEN SCORE_A2 > 100 THEN 0 ELSE SCORE_A2 END SCORE_A2,
    CASE WHEN SCORE_A3 > 100 THEN 0 ELSE SCORE_A3 END SCORE_A3
    FROM 
       (
        SELECT T.TICKET_NUMBER,
        SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 1 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 2 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN AREA_ID = 3 THEN QA.SCORE ELSE 0 END) SCORE_A3
        FROM QA INNER JOIN SKILLS S ON QA.SKILL_ID = S.SKILL_ID
        INNER JOIN TICKETS T ON QA.TICKET_ID = T.TICKET_ID
        WHERE QA.USER = :P2_USER GROUP BY T.TICKET_NUMBER
       ) TIX
   ) MORE_TIX
```